# Accesing javascript variable in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to accessing javascript variable and then change it in controller and then use it in route.. but it is showing the same old one.

```
var userEditid = 0;

app.controller("cn_newuser", function ($scope,$window) {
    editUser = function (this_) {
        $window.userEditid = this_.firstElementChild.value;
        alert(userEditid);
        //window.location.path("#/edit_user");
        //$window.location.href = "#/edit_user";
    }
```

route

```
.when("/edit_user", {   
    templateUrl: "/master/edituser/" + userEditid  //userEditid  should be 3 or some thing else but is showing 0
})
```

in abobe route userEditid  should be 3 or some thing else but is showing 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `.when()` is evaluated on app instantiation, when this global var (which is really not a great idea anyways) is set to `0`, rather than when your controller is run. If you are trying to say, "load the template, but the template name should vary based on a particular variable," then the way you are doing it isn't going to work.

I would do 2 things here:

1. Save your variable in a service, so you don't play with global vars
2. Have a master template, which uses an ng-include, which has the template determined by that var

Variable in a service:

```
app.controller("cn_newuser", function ($scope,UserIdService) {
   $scope.editUser = function (this_) {
       UserIdService.userEditid = this_.firstElementChild.value;
       $location.path('/edit_user');
   }
});
```

also note that I changed it to use `$location.path()`

Master template:

```
.when("/edit_user", {   
    templateUrl: "/master/edituser.html", controller: 'EditUser'
});
```

EditUser controller:

```
    app.controller("EditUser", function ($scope,UserIdService) {
       $scope.userTemplate = '/master/edituser/'+UserIdService.userEditId;
    });
```

And then edituser.html would be:

```
<div ng-include="userTemplate"></div>
```

Of course, I would ask why you would want a separate template per user, rather than a single template that is dynamically modified by Angular, but that is not what you asked.

EDITED:

Service would be something like

```
app.factory('UserIdService',function() {
  return {
    userEditId: null
  }
});
```

As simple as that.

Comment: thanks... i am new to angular... can u show me what would be service code\

Comment: Yeah, you have a fiddle up somewhere?

Comment: And don't feel badly; angular is fabulous, but the learning curve is steep and the tutorials are terrible. More and more come online every day though.

Comment: Sure. If you have any issues, throw it up into a fiddle and share it.